# Convert enumerator to lazy enumerator

Tags: ruby

An enumerator can be converted into a lazy enumerator using [Enumerator::Lazy.new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerator/Lazy.html#method-c-new) like this (this is an example; at the beginning, I already have an enumerator, not an array):

```
xs_enum = [1, 2, 3].to_enum
# => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each>
xs_lazy_enum = Enumerator::Lazy.new(xs_enum, &:yield)
# => #<Enumerator::Lazy: #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each>:each>
xs_lazy_enum.force
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

Is there a more succinct way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
[1, 2, 3].to_enum.lazy
# => #<Enumerator::Lazy: ...>
```

> Indeed, but the problem is that I start from an enumerator, not from an array

That doesn't change anything:

```
enum = (1..10).each
# => #<Enumerator: ...>
enum.lazy
# => #<Enumerator::Lazy: ...>
```

`Enumerable#to_enum` returns an enumerator. If you chain a call to `Enumerable#lazy` the receiver of the second message is the Enumerator returned by the first call.

Comment: Thanks, there is some subtility here, the output of your snippet and mine are slightly different: `=> #<Enumerator::Lazy: #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each>>` vs `#<Enumerator::Lazy: #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each>:each>`. I'll change the example in the question.

Comment: You are right! At the end this difference is not relevant when the enumerator is used, so a simple `enum.lazy` is the way to go.

Comment: Very good answer to an interesting question. Why not just start your answer with the line `enum = (1..10).each`.

Answer (score 8):

You can directly call `lazy` on the array (or enumerator).

```
[1, 2, 3].lazy
# => #<Enumerator::Lazy: [1, 2, 3]>
```

Comment: Beautifully simple answer!